# Create and merge GitHub pull requests API C#

Tags: c#, github, github-api, pull-request

I am creating a scheduled tool for merging changes to my GitHub repository on a daily basis. For this I need the tool to do the following function

- Checkout a branch (working branch) and pull it with the latest changes from the target branch
- Make the changes in the working branch which needs to be merged in the target branch.
- Commit the modified files into the remote working branch.
- Create the pull request from the working branch to the target branch.
- Merge the pull request that is created.

I was able to achieve the first 3 points above using the PowerShell command and the GitHub access token. I am stuck in the part of creating the pull request and merging them. I have followed the below documentation for the same but the API call is returning the Not found.

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-pull-request

Sample code used based on the above documentation

```
RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest("repos/" + GitHubUserId + "/" + "working-repository", Method.POST);
restRequest.Parameters.Clear();
restRequest.AddHeader("accept", "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
restRequest.AddParameter("head", sourceBranch);
restRequest.AddParameter("base", targetBranch);
restRequest.AddParameter("title", title);
restRequest.AddParameter("body", description);
```

https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/blob/main/docs/demos/exploring-pull-requests.md

Sample code used based on the above documentation using Octokit package.

```
GitHubClient gitHubClient = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GitHubUserId"].ToString(), "v1.0.0"));
gitHubClient.Credentials = new Credentials(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GitHubAccessToken"].ToString());
NewPullRequest newPullRequest = new NewPullRequest(title, sourceBranch, targetBranch);
var octokitRepo = await gitHubClient.Repository.Get("Organization", "working-reposiory");
var pullRequest = await gitHubClient.PullRequest.Create("Organization", "working-reposiory", newPullRequest);
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the game but should be what you need and for others arriving late.

```
public async Task DoItAll(string personalAccessToken)
{
    var ownerName = "Organization";
    var repositoryName = "Repository Name";
    var defaultBranchName = "heads/main";
    var featureBranchName = "refs/heads/feature-branch";

    var client = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("AppName"))
    {
        Credentials = new Credentials(personalAccessToken)
    };

    var repo = await client.Repository.Get(ownerName, repositoryName);
    var defaultBranch = await client.Git.Reference.Get(ownerName, repositoryName, defaultBranchName);
    var featureBranch = await client.Git.Reference.Create(ownerName,
        repositoryName,
        new NewReference(featureBranchName, defaultBranch.Object.Sha));
    //Must commit at least one change to feature branch prior to creating PR, code omitted
    var pr = await client.PullRequest.Create(repo.Id,
        new NewPullRequest("PR Title", featureBranch.Ref, defaultBranch.Ref));
    var newMerge = new NewMerge(defaultBranch.Ref, featureBranch.Ref);
    await client.Repository.Merging.Create(repo.Id, newMerge);
}
```